# Android Gallery View showing two view on a single screen.

Tags: java, android, layout, gallery

I'm designing a Gallery View in Android where I need to have two views occupying each half of the screen (2 views on a full screen). When the user scrolls it shows the next view. The Ideas behind this is to have five views and user see 2 views initially. I tried a couple options but without success,where setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2)); didn't really solve the problem. If anybody encountered this kind if an issue send me an advice or path. Thank you for reading and please let me know if you need any further details in case if I didn't make my self clear.

Answer (score 1):

`two views occupying each half of the screen (2 views on a full screen)`
to acheive this give both the views equal weight so that both takes equal height(half - half screen). then in the
`setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2));`
instead of setting the screenwidth/2 and height/2 use fill parent there...
Hope it helps...
if found any issues with this... post your layout and code relevant to that...

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response. Your answer works perfectly with the standard layouts but when dealing with Gallery widget the behavior of views changes. So my problem is really having a Gallery of 5 Views where each view occupies a position in the Gallery my ultimate goal is having this Gallery Showing position 1 and 2 on the screen each one of them occupying half of the screen (by position I mean views at position). Thanks for Reading.